# Document classification with incomplete training set

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, document-classification

Advice please. I have a collection of documents that all share a common attribute (e.g. The word French appears) some of these documents have been marked as not pertinent to this collection (e.g. French kiss appears) but not all documents are guaranteed to have been identified. What is the best method to use to figure out which other documents don't belong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assumptions

Given your example "French", I will work under the assumption that the feature is a word that appears in the document. Also, since you mention that "French kiss" is not relevant, I will further assume that in your case, a feature is a word used in a particular sense. For example, if "pool" is a feature, you may say that documents mentioning swimming pools are relevant, but those talking about pool (the sport, like snooker or billiards) are not relevant.

- **Note**: Although *word sense disambiguation* (WSD) methods would work, they require too much effort, and is an overkill for this purpose.

#### Suggestion: *localized* language model + bootstrapping

Think of it this way: You don't have an incomplete training set, but a smaller training set. The idea is to use this small training data to build bigger training data. This is ***bootstrapping***.

For each occurrence of your feature in the training data, build a language model based only on the words surrounding it. You don't need to build a model for the entire document. Ideally, just the sentences containing the feature should suffice. This is what I am calling a ***localized language model*** (LLM).

Build two such LLMs from your training data (let's call it T_0): one for pertinent documents, say M1, and another for irrelevant documents, say M0. Now, to build a bigger training data, classify documents based on M1 and M0. For every new document *d*, if *d* does not contain the feature-word, it will automatically be added as a "bad" document. If *d* contains the feature-word, then consider a local window around this word in *d* (the same window size that you used to build the LLMs), and compute the perplexity of this sequence of words with M0 and M1. Classify the document as belonging to the class which gives lower perplexity.

To formalize, the pseudo-code is:

```
T_0 := initial training set (consisting of relevant/irrelevant documents)
D0 := additional data to be bootstrapped
N := iterations for bootstrapping

for i = 0 to N-1
  T_i+1 := empty training set
  Build M0 and M1 as discussed above using a window-size w
  for d in D0
    if feature-word not in d
    then add d to irrelevant documents of T_i+1
    else
      compute perplexity scores P0 and P1 corresponding to M0 and M1 using
      window size w around the feature-word in d.
      if P0 < P1 - delta
        add d to irrelevant documents of T_i+1
      else if P1 < P0 - delta
        add d to relevant documents of T_i+1
      else
        do not use d in T_i+1
      end
    end
  end
  Select a small random sample from relevant and irrelevant documents in
  T_i+1, and (re)classify them manually if required.
end
```

- T_N is your final training set. In this above bootstrapping, the parameter *delta* needs to be determined with experiments on some *held-out* data (also called *development* data).
- The manual reclassification on a small sample is done so that the noise during this bootstrapping is not accumulated through all the *N* iterations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly you should **take care of how to extract features** of the sample docs. Counting every word is not a good way. You might need some technique like TFIDF to teach the classifier that which words are important to classify and which are not.
2. **Build a right dictionary**. In your case, the word **French kiss** should be a unique word, instead of a sequence of French + kiss. Use the right technique to build a right dictionary is important.
3. The remain errors in samples are normal, we call it "**not linear separable**". There're a huge amount of advanced researches on how to solve this problem. For example, **SVM** (support vector machine) would be what you like to use. Please note that single-layer Rosenblatt perceptron usually shows very bad performance for the dataset which are not linear separable.

Answer (score -1):

1. Some kinds of neural networks (like Rosenblatt perceptron) can be educated on erroneus data set and can show a better performance than tranier has. Moreover in many cases you should make  errors for avoid over-training.
2. You can mark all unlabeled documents randomly, train several nets and estimate theirs performance on the test set (of course, you should not include unlabeled documents in the test set). After that you can in cycle recalculate weights of unlabeled documents as w_i = sum of quality(j) * w_ij, and then repeate training and the recalculate weight and so on. Because procedure is equivalent to introducing new hidden layer and recalculating it weights by Hebb procedure the overall procedure should converge if your positive and negative sets are lineary separable in some network feature space.

Comment: I don't agree. The single-layer Rosenblatt perceptron shows very bad performance for the dataset which are not linear separable.